# Weird Ubuntu 14.04 Post-Install Issues

Tags: gparted, reboot

Firstly, thank you for the help last night with the catastrophe that ruined my 12.04 to 14.04 LTS upgrade. I'm now comfortably running 14.04 with all my data back and all is well in the world. I'm just having some really weird post install issues with 14.04 that I'm having trouble finding information on:

1.) Reboot from terminal is not functional - As in the command "sudo reboot now". I had to add the reboot=pci flag to /etc/default/grub and run sudo grub-update to make regular reboot work, but reboot now currently hangs on a black screen, and when I press the power button, shuts down the computer, not restarts it. It's not that big of a deal but it's still weird.

2.) When I launch GParted, it hangs on "searching /dev/sda partitions..." forever. This was previously working on 12.04 and I would like it to work on 14.04. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common causes of "searching ... partitions..." taking an long time are:  (1) A floppy device is enabled in the BIOS, but there is no physical floppy device,  (2) A partition contains a highly fragmented FAT16/32 or NTFS file system - fix with defragmenting first.